# IBM Mobile First 6.3 Error:runtime environment could not be launched

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

I am having error ''**runtime environment could not be launched**'' in my development environment
Environment details are:
Eclipse Kepler
Java:1.7
Mobile First:6.3
OS:Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

This is frequent error while setting up the development env.
try switching your java runtime in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-install everything. Looks like an environment error. Make sure you selected Text File Encoding as "UTF-8" in windows --> preferences --> general --> workspace of your eclipse.